# Apache webserver - setting dns for subdomain

Tags: apache, dns, centos

I have a website let's name it www.website.ro which runs on apache server, centos.
I do not have a cpanel or whm but I have acces to centos throught ssh.

I already set VirtualHost for my main domain and subdomain but I don't know how can I make my subdomain visible from internet.
I know that is something related to DNS and things like CNAME, but I don't know where to put them in apache's files.

By the way my main domain is already visible on the internet,now i want to make the subdomain visible as well.

I have edited httpd conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
    ServerName  www.website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
    ServerName subdomain.website.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.website.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes to Apache's configuration tell it to handle requests for the subdomain if it receives them, but won't affect the DNS entries that visitors need to find your subdomain in the first place.

To make your subdomain visible you have to add entries to your DNS zone, which is handled by your ISP or registrar.

You have to make changes in both places to make your new subdomain work.

Comment: Ok, but on websites that have CPANEL installed, I don't need to do anything related to my registrar. On my registrar I only need to set ns for my main domain and after that I can create as many subdomain as I want. How CPANEL does this ?

Comment: If your hosting company is also providing DNS service for your domains than CPanel has access to both webserver and DNS server and makes both sets of changes automatically. In this case one company is acting as registrar, DNS service and host. These are three different functions and can potentially be handled by three separate organisations.

Comment: So, in order to create subdomains i need to have access to my DNS server right ? I don't need to change anything in my registrar since I already set ns for my main domain, right ?