# Difference between internal and external DNS?

Tags: apache, redirect, server, dns

I need to make redirection of domain. It should point to my IP address. The problem is that internal DNS is configured correctly but external DNS shows bad IP.

Could you explain what is the difference between internal and external DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your domain to resolve to specific IP from any location, you must update the DNS zone file of your Authoritative DNS server, which most probabily will be your domain registrar's DNS servers. 
Go to DNS settings of your domain's Authoritative DNS server and add an A record with IP address of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Internal as the DNS that may provide you firewall, it is your own DNS that is resolving (or forwarding requests) in your internal LAN. On the other side, the external DNS is the public DNS that resolves the domain request from internet.

If you are using internal DNS you thoud point it to your internal IP address, on the External DNS you whoud point it to your public IP.

Comment: thanks for response, do you know how to set it through apache?

Comment: Apache have nothing to do with DNS, it will respond to VirtuaHost request, and is DNS configuration that will make clients reach apache. Take a look at this question, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965320/apache-webserver-setting-dns-for-subdomain